# I have deleted Bitcoin core but it keeps restarting and taking the storage

Tags: bitcoin-core

I m using Bitcoin Core version v0.21.1. My problem is that even after deleting the Bitcoin folder in the application support, the bitcoin folder reappears in 2-3 days. This morning I saw another bitcoin folder in the application support. It's been going on for about 4 months now. When I checked launchctl list, I saw org.bitcoin.bitcoind. Not sure what this means tho.

Im using Mac os ver 11.5.2

deleted:Application Support/Bitcoin

'Start Bitcoin Core on system login' Not checked in GUI

Comment: Which OS? Which folder did you delete? Is 'Start Bitcoin Core on system login' checked in GUI? Did you create any service or cronjobs or scheduled tasks?

Comment: I added the answers to your question in the OP.